# Узнать путь логирования NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

Имеется (легаси)проект на ASP.Net MVC, в котором используется NLog. Пытаюсь выяснить, где хранятся логи. Конфигурации в файле конфига нет. `LogManager.Configuration` в рантайме пустой. Код использования NLog следующий:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(<loggerName>);
...
logger.Log(typeof(NLog.Logger), <logInfo>);
```

Поиск на диске по данному  ничего не дал. Никак не пойму, как в этом случае работает NLog. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в `NLog.config` подобную строчку:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
    fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/LogFile.txt"/>
```

Полезные ссылки:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config
- https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.3.0/html/Properties_T_NLog_LayoutRenderers_SpecialFolderLayoutRenderer.htm
- https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Special-Folder-Layout-Renderer

UPD:

```
private static readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

public static string ProgramName => $"[{Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName}]";

public static void Warn(string message) 
{ 
    _logger.Warn($"{ProgramName}\n{message}"); 
    Console.WriteLine(message); 
}
```

Comment: Наверное, удивлю, но файла ```NLog.config``` тоже нет) Какие-то еще способы указания конфигурации есть?

Comment: @АлександрПертенава Но я ведь в полезных ссылках указал nuget-пакет, с помощью которого можно получить этот файл....

Comment: да, спасибо. Параллельный вопрос: если в ```LogManager.GetLogger()``` передать имя, для которого не прописан конфиг, то NLog кинет ошибку или нет?

Comment: @АлександрПертенава Обновил ответ и привёл пример, как можно логировать. ProgramName - имя проекта, который вызвал этот метод. Если у вас несколько проектов, каждый из которых нужно логировать, это должно помочь в разборе логов. На ваш вопрос ответить не смогу, т.к. давненько уже перешёл с NLog на Serilog, потому что просто удобнее (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1422209/378277 пример использования)

Answer (score 0):

По итогу использования святого метода "тыка" могу сказать, что NLog не бросает ошибки при отсутствии конфигурации. Проблема решилась добавлением этого самого файла конфигурации с указанием стандартных разделов `targets` и `rules`. В моём случае (если кому-то пригодится):

```
<шапка файла...>
<targets>
<target name="SiteWorkflowFile"
        xsi:type="File"
        fileName="C:\Logs\SiteWorkflow\${date:format=yyyyMMdd}.log"
        createDirs="true"
        concurrentWrites="true"
        deleteOldFileOnStartup="false"
        header="TimeStamp;LogLevel;Ip;Message"
        layout="${longdate};${level};${event-context:message}" />
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="SiteWorkflow" writeTo="SiteWorkflowFile" />
</rules>
```